# Open new window "The calling thread must be STA"

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, outlook

I know that there is lots of questions about "The calling thread..." but the way I tried didn´t solve my problem, and I know that I have to include a thread call but I don´t know where.

So, I create a mailItem and add the send and close event handler as below, if the mail item is closed I do nothing, if the mail item is sent I have to open a window to user to register a sort of history.

The error occurs when I try to create the window to register the history.

Step 1:

```
((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)mailItem).Send += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemEvents_10_SendEventHandler(EmailEnviado);

((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)mailItem).Close += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemEvents_10_CloseEventHandler(EmailCancelado);
```

Step 2

```
mailItem.Display();
```

Step 3

```
private void EmailEnviado(ref bool 
{
           List<int> listaPendenciaId = new List<int>();

            foreach (Pendencia pendencia in this.listaPendencia)
            {
                if (pendencia.IsSelecionado)
                {
                    listaPendenciaId.Add(pendencia.
            System.Windows.Window historicoEmailCadastro = new System.Windows.Window
                    {
                        Title = "Cadastro de Histórico de Email",
                        Content = new HistoricoEmailCadastro(listaPendenciaId),
                        Width = 249,
                        Height = 213,
                        ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize
                    };

            historicoEmailCadastro.ShowDialog();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Microsoft Office APIs are COM based and COM objects need to be accessed in the same thread they were created.

Comment: Hmm, there is something wrong with the way you initialize Outlook's Application object.  Like creating it on a worker thread.  We can't see that code but you ought to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call all UI stuff only from UI thread.

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{       
    ///....
        System.Windows.Window historicoEmailCadastro = new System.Windows.Window
        {
            Title = "Cadastro de Histórico de Email",
            Content = new HistoricoEmailCadastro(listaPendenciaId),
            Width = 249,
            Height = 213,
            ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize
        };

    historicoEmailCadastro.ShowDialog();
});
```

More info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Thanks very much tym!